# changing the colour of a cell using mysql query result at javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, json

```js
<script>
var blocation = <?php echo json_encode($json_location); ?>;
var paintBeacon = function() {
  $('#zoning')
    .find('tr td#', +beacon)
    .css('background-color', location);
}
</script>
<script>
var trackview = "<table id=zoning><tbody><tr>";
 
for (var i =1; i < 101; i++) {
    if (i % 10 == 1 && i != 1) {
        trackview += "</tr><tr>";
    }
    trackview += "<td id="+ i +">"+ i +"</td>";
}
 
trackview += "</tr></tbody></table>";
 
document.write(trackview)
</script>
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cellpadding: 2;
  cellspacing: 2;
  width: "100%";
  height: "100%";
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 48px;
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
}
```

I have created a pastebin with my code in it contains my html code, php code, and css code.

the overall goal that i have is that if the bnumber is the same as the number in a cell then the colour of that cell changing to the colour represented by the location of the beacon, I use a mysql table to store the data of the beacon and the location and can retrieve that okay with my php file i then push it through to the html file using json_encode but i can get it to work, where am i going wrong.

sorry im new to this type of coding.

```
             <?php 
             $dbhost = '192.168.0.54:3306'; 
             $dbuser = 'track'; 
             $dbpass = 'Ostrich17!'; 

             $conn = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect($dbhost,  
             $dbuser,                   
             $dbpass)); 

             if(! $conn ) { 
             die('Could not connect: ' .                  
             ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ?                  
             mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res =                  
             mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false))); 
             } 

             $sql = 'select beacon,location from location.location where 
             time="10:38";'; 
             ((bool)mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "USE " .                  
             'location')); 
             $retval = mysqli_query( $conn ,  $sql); 

             if(! $retval ) { 
             die('Could not get data: ' .                                   
             ((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ?                  

             mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res =                                    
             mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
             } 

             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval,  MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
             echo "beacon : {$row['beacon']} <br> ".
             "location : {$row['location']} <br> ";   
              } 

             echo "Fetched beacon successfully\n"; 

             $json_location = json_encode($retval);

             mysqli_close($conn);
             ?>
```

Comment: btw; you've a few questions from the past with answers given but none were accepted. Did they not solve those? You never even commented about them.

Comment: You have to put your code here. Not as external resource

Comment: Maybe use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) instead of pastebin, or post code here using [SO snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Hi Guys thank you for commenting the answers that i received i did try but unfortunately none of those worked , the reason i used pastebin is due the the amount of code that is supplied in the pastebin and i didnt think that js fiddle allowed php code in it.

Comment: @AvalonParkes-barton, if you want you can use [SO Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for your front-end code and [format your back-end code .](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Dwhitz Thank you I did not know about that function I have now updated my post so i hope that is a bit better for you guys.

Comment: why are you making 2 DB calls to the same table with the same criteria? You can make one query and return both fields at the same time.

Comment: `json_encode($retval2)` won't return the location(s), it will return the mysqli_result object. You want to be putting the value(s) of `$row['location']` into that, within your loop.

Comment: @ADyson I did have it as 1 query but i thought that i may not be able to split the query result into 2 variables, so what i want is that if the bnumber is the same as the value in the html cell then change the .css background for that cell to the blocation colour.

Comment: if you did it as one query, then `$row['location']` and `$row['beacon'']` would be separate variables you could access within the same row. That's one of the basic principles of using PHP / MySQL. Perhaps you should take one of the many online tutorials available to get some of the core concepts in your head, it would make life a bit easier.

Comment: I've also just noticed that you're using the mysql_* libraries. These were deprecated several years ago, and removed entirely in PHP7 due to security concerns. If you're writing new code, you should always use the mysqli_* or PDO libraries, and ensure you use parameterised queries when you get to the stage of needing parameters. Again there's plenty of material online demonstrating these.

Comment: @ADyson thank you i will look into that